Modeling sales of a market in a country
As a student I got a task to model a particular market in a particular country.
A company, my teacher collaborate with, provided to us a sales dataset that contains:
30 product families and 60 products
Monthly sales records for 30 months for each product for each of ~1000 small geolocations.
EDA has shown that sales in a small geolocation are quote fluctuating, so I merged small geolocations to middle (30 in the country) and big ones (6 in the country) according to a geostructure of product promoters.
After that, I found several patterns in sales:

Total sales of all products in the country and in each middle and big geolocation have very small down trend (we can assume that it's constant), specified by the quite constant number of buyers.
Seasoning. Season up/down-trends, sales maximum and minimum occur in particular months. The variation of these fluctuations depends of the product and varies from 5 upto 30%. Season fluctuation of the market is 7%.
There are early introduced products with clear up-trend. They substitute some old products (down-trends).
Some irregularities varying year-over-year.

I should train a ML model predicting sales of the given products, but have scarce experience with ML. From my point of view there is not enough monthly data for a good model. Correct me if I am wrong.
Can somebody give me a hint about a Neural Network or another prediction prediction technique.
